# How to properly remove an extra disk from VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, xubuntu, storage, sata, vdi

I have this vm with Xubuntu and I've added 4 extra disks (practising for a course I'm taking).

[image]

How do I remove them? Just by selecting and removing? will this break anything? thanks!

[image]

Comment: What does it have to do with Xubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove them in 3 steps.

1. Remove/disable these storage devices in your virtual machine OS (if needed)
2. Remove these storage devices in your hypervisor (VirtualBox)
3. If needed, delete the image files of these virtual storage devices on your host system, to free disk space